# Wordpress Gutenberg block editor: When using Nested Blocks how to access and save child block data in parent block?

Tags: wordpress, editor, wordpress-gutenberg

My use case is this:
I have a NestedBlock that can only accept 1 type of child block. Think link accordion type of block.

I can add as many child blocks as I want.
When I save I want to save a nav element in the parent block that links with anchors to every child element in the InnerBlocks.

How do I do that?

I've read issues mentioning to do the reverse, accessing the parent data or attributes from the child block but not in the other way around.

Currently my save function looks something like this
As you can see I tried several things that did not work and the editor keeps returning errors and not saving the content.

```
   save: ( {attributes, innerBlocks } ) => {
        const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();
        const blocks = select('core/block-editor').getBlocks();
        console.log(innerBlocks);
        const anchorLinks = '';
        if ( Array.isArray(innerBlocks) ) {
            console.log("all right");

            // Generate anchor links for each child block
            const anchorLinks = innerBlocks.map((childBlock) => {
                // Assuming that the child block has a 'uniqueId' attribute
                const childUniqueId = childBlock.attributes.uniqueId;
                console.log(childUniqueId);
        
                // Return the anchor link
                return <a href={`#${childUniqueId}`}>Child Block: {childUniqueId}</a>;
            });
        }



        return (
            <div { ...blockProps }>

                {/* <ul class="tabs-controls">
                    {innerBlocks.map((block) => (
                        <li class="accordion-mobile-heading">
                            <button class="accordion accordion__control active" aria-expanded={block.attributes.showContent } aria-controls={ block.attributes.uniqueId }>
                                    { block.attributes.heading }
                            </button>
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul> */}
                { anchorLinks }
                <InnerBlocks.Content />
            </div>
        );
    },
```